# When I am root, "mysql" connects without a password, even though I've set one

Tags: mysql, password

When I am root, "mysql" connects without a password, even though I've set one:

```
# mysqladmin -u root password 'whatever'
# mysql -u root -p
Enter password: (typing the 'whatever' above)
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 4 to server version: 4.1.22-standard

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the buffer.

mysql> Bye
```

but unfortunately this also happens...

```
# mysql -u root 
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 25 to server version: 4.1.22-standard

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the buffer.

mysql>
```

So even though I've set the password, and it IS checked when I use "-p",
it is however not necessary!?!?

Comment: Check your [.my.cnf](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql_intro.html#SECTION0001500000) config file for the lines `user=root` and `password=pass`. Do they exist? If so, that's why you're able to log in without a password. Deleting those lines should correct that.

Comment: Cross-post: http://serverfault.com/q/279411/51929

Answer (score 1):

Check your [.my.cnf](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql_intro.html#SECTION0001500000) config file for the lines `user=root` and `password=whatever`. These enable you to log in without a username or password. Delete those lines if you want to be prompted for a password instead.